# Error C2385 mbiguous access of 'InternalQueryInterface'

Tags: c++, mfc, com, atl

I have created an ATL project with MFC support for my project requirement, but while building by solutions begin_com_map which defined inside my .h file throws an ambiguous error.

Please find the below code files, let me know if something is wrong. Thanks!

IDL file:

```
// Config.idl : IDL source for Config

// This file will be processed by the MIDL tool to
// produce the type library (Config.tlb) and marshaling code.

import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(2C79CBDC-AFFD-4E02-B319-806A19E179CE),
    pointer_default(unique)
]

interface IBuilderCallback : IUnknown
{
    [id(1)]
    HRESULT Notify([in] UINT loadPhase, [in] UINT res);
};

[
    object,
    uuid(E5BCF0D1-1EF5-4EBD-94A2-2CD3F8679AB4),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IBuilder : IDispatch
{

    [id(1)]
    HRESULT Init([in]BSTR bstrHMFilePath, [out] IBuilderCallback 
    **callback);

};

[
   uuid(8b6427a7-2fb2-4b28-98a4-ce97a1b57c30),
   version(1.0),
]
library TPNConfigServiceLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        uuid(451DC15B-CE14-4277-B977-37ECF43C20EE)
    ]
    coclass CBuilder
    {
        [default] interface IBuilder;
    };

    [
        uuid(C9114319-1111-4A36-AD9E-503C5A4E2DEC)
    ]
    coclass BuilderCallback
    {
        [default] interface IBuilderCallback;
    };
};
```

.H file :

```
pragma once
#include "Resource.h"
#include "Config_i.h"
#include <atlbase.h>


#if defined(_WIN32_WCE) && !defined(_CE_DCOM) && 
!defined(_CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA)
#error "Single-threaded COM objects are not properly supported on Windows 
CE platform, such as the Windows Mobile platforms that do not include 
full DCOM support. Define _CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA to 
force ATL to support creating single-thread COM object's and allow use of 
it's single-threaded COM object implementations. The threading model in 
your rgs file was set to 'Free' as that is the only threading model 
supported in non DCOM Windows CE platforms."
#endif

using namespace ATL;


class ATL_NO_VTABLE CBuilder :
     public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
     public CComCoClass<CBuilder, &CLSID_CBuilder>,
     public ISupportErrorInfo,
     public IDispatchImpl<IBuilder, &IID_IBuilder, &LIBID_ConfigLib, 
     /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
     public CCmdTarget
 {
 public:
      CBuilder();
      DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CBuilder)
      DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
      DECLARE_OLECREATE(CBuilder)
      DECLARE_DISPATCH_MAP()
      DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP()

     BEGIN_COM_MAP(CBuilder)
           COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IBuilder)
           COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch) 
     END_COM_MAP()

};
```

.CPP file :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TPNEntityBuilder.h"
```

After building the above files it results in an error: C2385 ambiguous access of 'InternalQueryInterface'

This error comes has InternalQueryInterface() is defined in 2 different classes ( base class of CComObjectRootEx, i.e CComObjectRootBase and CCmdTarget class).

Please help me in solving this, Thanks.

Comment: I think you're mixing MFC and ATL COM bases, you should use just one of the two. If it's ATL then there is no `CCmdTarget` and no `DECLARE_xxx` inside.

Comment: yeah it's the same kind, I'm doing it. because we are using some set of methods defined in CCmdTarget and we are migrating to ATL/COM with old code working.

Comment: Ditch the MFC stuff or ditch the ATL stuff. Implement your COM object using one or the other. I'd recommend using ATL.